# Shinobi Controls - use the hoop data point

Tags: ios, shinobi

I've got a test Shinobi Control chart working but wnat to put a hoop, "O", at each data point.
How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the point color on the series style object appropriately. The series which have the ability to show point (`SChartScatterSeries`, `SChartLineSeries`, `SChartBandSeries`) all have a `pointStyle` property within their style object, which is an instance of `SChartPointStyle`. This has the following relevant properties:

- `innerColor`
- `color`
- `innerRadius`
- `outerRadius`
- `showPoints`

Depending on the effect you want (and the series type you are using) you need to set these appropriately. For example, to show 'hoops' on an `SChartScatterSeries`, you could use the following for the data source method:

```
- (SChartSeries *)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart seriesAtIndex:(int)index
{
    _series = [SChartColumnSeries new];
    SChartScatterSeries *series = [SChartScatterSeries new];
    series.style.pointStyle.innerColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return series;
}
```

Note, if you're using `SChartBandSeries` or `SChartLineSeries`, these have `showPoints` set to `NO` by default, so you would need to set this to `YES` yourself.

Comment: did you have any luck with your problem?